# Erro ao usar fs.createReadStream('arquivo') para salvar um arquivo em um formData() em node

Tags: node.js, api

Olá, eu tento salvar um arquivo dentro de um formData() em nodeJs, mas quando eu verifico, a fs.createReadStream('arquivo') diz que foram lido 0 bytes. Alguém poderia me explicar porque isso está acontecendo? E se possível sugerir uma solução. Segue a parte do código:

```
let form = new FormData()
form.append('My_file', fs.createReadStream('arquivo.json'));
axios.post('URL_Qualquer', form)
         .then(response => { 
             console.log(response)
         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.log(error.response)
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente ele não está encontrando o arquivo.json. Você está passando o caminho correto do seu arquivo.json ?

Comment: sim, tenho total certeza

Comment: Então utilize as seguintes funcões:

//Evento para ler o arquivo. ( Caso tenha algo )
read_stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
});

// Evento de fim de texto.
read_stream.on('end',function(){
    // console do conteudo.
    console.log("Stream data is : " + data);
});

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, mas não compreendi direito. É para usar essa "read_stream.on()" para ler o arquivo? passando o caminho no data?

Comment: Oi, desculpe a demora.

var read_stream = fs.createReadStream('arquivo.json');

//Evento para ler o arquivo. ( Caso tenha algo )
 read_stream.on('data', function(chunk) { 
data += chunk; });

 // Evento de fim de texto. read_stream.on('end',function(){
 // console do conteudo. 
console.log("Stream data is : " + data); });

Comment: no caso o que seria o 'data' dentro do read_stream.on() ? Ao executar esse código eu recebo: data is not defined

Comment: data é a variable onde você irá guardar os dados. Vou te mandar uma URL para você ter melhor exito. https://www.dev2qa.com/node-js-stream-example/

Comment: opa, consegui ler o arquivo assim

Comment: Bom, deu certinho ai ?

Comment: a leitura do arquivo foi feita de forma correta, muito obrigado. Mas na parte em que faço a requisição com a api para enviar o arquivo eu continuo recebendo o erro de que o arquivo não foi lido. Mesmo que tenha aparecido o conteúdo dele no console.log()

Comment: você esta usando funções assíncronas para esperar a leitura do arquivo e depois enviar o conteúdo ?